# Image Upload and Class App\Image is not working in a Laravel Project hosted in a shared server

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have deployed a Laravel project in a shared hosting. I have changed my .env file and copied all files from the public folder to the main directory and deleted the public folder. Now the problem is, whenever I am trying to upload an image, I am getting an internal server error which I'm gonna show you in the image below. The another problem what i'm having is when i'm trying to watch the images. It says "Class 'App\image' not found". My project works fine on my local server and works fine on shared hosting too, except for the image problem.

This is the code of my Controller:

```
$cont=1;
    if($request->hasfile('image')){
        foreach($request->file('image') as $file){

            $name = 'blog'.$cont.time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $cont++;
            $path = public_path().'\images\articles\\';
            $file->move($path, $name);
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
     }


    $article = new Article($request->all());
    $article->user_id=\Auth::user()->id;
    $article->save();

    $article->tags()->sync($request->tags); //relacion muchos a muchos - belongsToMany()

     foreach($data as $dato){
        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $dato;
        $image->article()->associate($article); //relacion belongsTo() - hasMany()
        $image->save();
    }
```

[image: Error when I trying to add a new file]

[image: Error when I trying to get all the images]

Comment: Did you change your bootstrap and other links in index.php file?

Comment: yes, i did! the aplication works fine except for the images' problem

Comment: Ok try to dump autoload. Php artisan dump-autoload. Maybe that will help. Let me know

Comment: My shared hosting does not have ssh. Can I try in my local server and then update the project again? or what can i do?

Comment: Better do it on the server rather than local server because otherwise there would be no point. Setup ssh